# Merge [borrowing] and [borrow-checker]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Both the [borrow-checker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/borrow-checker) and [borrowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/borrowing) tags refer to the Rust borrow checker. Please, merge them.